# Calling Webservices via code security for logging onto service (.NET / WCF)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, security

My web app is going to call a webservice.

I'm looking for best practices / guidance for logging onto the webservice so I know that an authorized user is trying to access it not just anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A Good Article on Authorization in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx).  It discusses many of the options.